# Uniqueness of module over zero ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

The Wikipedia page for zero ring says that the only module for the zero ring is the zero module. Why is this true? It seems to me that any abelian group would be a $0$-module. Is it because we are assuming the module is unital so that $0 \cdot x= x$ for all $x$ so $x=0$? (Note that $0=1$ in the zero ring.)

Comment: If you follow up Wikipedia’s link to their page on [modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)?wprov=sfti1), you will see that they require modules to be unital.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if $R$ is any ring, and $M$ is (left) $R$-module, then $0_Rm=0_M$ for all $m\in M$. This, just as in the vector space case, is because
$$ 0_Rm = (0_R+0_R)m = 0_Rm+0_Rm$$
and therefore $0_Rm=0_M$. Note that this holds whether the module is unital or not.

If $R$ is the zero ring, and we require the action to be unital, then for any (left) $R$-module $M$ we have $1_Rm = m$; on the other hand, since $1_R=0_R$, then by the above we have $0_Rm=0_M$. Thus,
$$0_M = 0_Rm = 1_Rm = m,$$
so every element of $M$ is trivial. That is, $M=\{0_M\}$. Wikipedia requires modules to be unital, as you can see in their [formal definition of modules, property 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)?wprov=sfti1).

If you don’t require modules to be unital, then any abelian group would be a (left) $R$-module over the zero ring, with action $0_Rm=0_M$.